# Select Multiple Materialize no mobile

Tags: mobile, materialize

Estou com uma dúvida no **select multiple** do Materialize para mobile. 
Não consigo selecionar outra opção, diferente do Bootstrap que ao clicar fora do campo, ele sai automaticamente.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

```js
/* Select */
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

```html
<h5 class="margintext">Pesquise seu imóvel</h5>
            <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l3">
              <select multiple>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Finalidade</option>
                <option value="1">Venda</option>
                <option value="2">Aluguel</option>
                <option value="3">Aluguel temporada</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l3">
              <select multiple>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Cidades</option>
                <option value="1">Capão da Canoa</option>
                <option value="2">Porto Alegre</option>
                <option value="3">Imbé</option>
                <option value="3">Caxias</option>
              </select>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l3">
              <select multiple>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Bairros</option>
                <option value="1">Cetro</option>
                <option value="2">Zona Nova</option>
                <option value="3">Navegantes</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Quem estiver com o mesmo problema basta colar esse script

```
$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {
    let target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.is("span")) { //checking if you are tapping on items in multiple select or not
        $(document).trigger('click'); //if you are tapping outside multiple select close it
        $(':focus').blur(); //focus out for multiple select so you can choose another or the same (in case you have more multiple selects on page)
    } else {
        //nothing or fire another event
    };
});
```